# DNS issue connecting from remote domain to exchange

Tags: domain-name-system

OK I think I have a DNS issue.

The situation-

I have multiple servers in the main office and everything works fine, one of which is primary DNS server (ServerA) and one is the Exchange Server (ServerB)

I have another SBS in another domain that is a DNS Server for the remote location (ServerC) with a secondary DNS record of ServerA

My problem is that 2 XP workstations in the remote location will not connect to exchange using outlook if the DNS record is automatic or if statically configured to ServerC. The user can connect to ServerA with VPN and exchange connects however this is not desirable. If DNS is configured as ServerA then Exchange also connects however this causes other issues (scanning, etc cannot connect to the workstation using ip address)

Other workstations seem to be OK and configured without Exchange Proxy HTTP connection  except for these 2 machines running XP (either way this does not work either).

On serverC DNS records all hostnames match IP addresses

Please help if you can assist I cannot get the Exchange working with the DNS server they should be using, any ideas of what else to try, check? I have tried all outlook settings and duplicated settings from other working machines as well?

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified basic network connectivity?  No Windows firewall etc?  Try out PortQry and test basic Exchange connectivity tests.  The fact that it works with VPN leads me to believe there are differences at the networking level between the workstations that work, and the ones that dont. Different subnets etc.

Comment: Yes network connectivity is fine. Everything in the remote location is same subnet. Everything else except exchange works fine- internet, network sharing, etc. when using the required DNS (ServerC). Exchange works when using DNS of ServerA or VPN. Therefore the problem is somehow that the DNS of ServerC does not propagate/talk to ServerA so Exchange cannot connect. Notably machines running windows 7 seem to automatically handle whatever the issue is? Thanks

Comment: I think you need to propagate the DNS zone from server C to server A. A wants to resolve the name of the connecting client (reverse DNS) but the client is in the DNS of C. Not in the DNS that A uses.

Comment: Yes I think this sounds like what I want to do, how? Notably regardless of DNS settings all workstations can ping remote servers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your above question, create a secondary zone on server A for the domain of server C.  Configure zone transfers on Server C to allow transfer from server A.

And if I understand the above poster, you will want to create a secondary zone for the reverse IP lookup zone of Server C on Server A as well.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816885(v=ws.10).aspx